# Want to show alert box for only 3 seconds

Tags: javascript

I want to show alert box only for 3 seconds (Means it show & hide automatically). I have search lot of in google but doesn't get answer. Any suggestion really appreciated.

I have done with new window but still finding solution with alert box.  Chk My code :

```
function fn() {
    var w = window.open('', '', 'width=300,height=2px')
    w.document.write('Product has been added to your Order List !')
    w.focus()
    setTimeout(function () { w.close(); }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: This isn't a code request forum. Please try something and come back with a specific problem you are facing with your solution.

Comment: The only way to hide an `alert()` box is by user interaction.

Comment: The user has to manually close an alert box by clicking ok. If you need to show alert and fade away, use jquery or simple solution is to use a div as shown in this post

    `function tempAlert(msg,duration)
    {
     var el = document.createElement("div");
     el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:40%;left:20%;background-color:white;");
     el.innerHTML = msg;
     setTimeout(function(){
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     },duration);
     document.body.appendChild(el);
    }`

Call this function from code behind or from the click of any button.

Comment: Thanks all for your view !

Comment: I didn't vote for off-topic, this question is not off topic. But it is a duplicate of lot of other questions here.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot hide or cancel an alert() box automatically from JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

```
function tempAlert(msg,duration)

    {
     var el = document.createElement("div");
     el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:40%;left:20%;background-color:white;");
     el.innerHTML = msg;
     setTimeout(function(){
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     },duration);
     document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
```

Use this like this:

```
tempAlert("close",5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you would like to control all this using javascript. With native alert boxes (the ones using `alert()`), you cannot do this.

What you could do is to use an alternative such as [JQuery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal). It is generated from javascript, so you would have a possibility of closing it from javascript as well. You could use `setTimeout()` to activate 3 second timeout, and `$('#your-dialog-id').dialog( "close" );` to close the modal dialog.